# protobuf serializetocodedstream returns "false"

Tags: c++, qt, protocol-buffers

I am trying to serialize my Protocol Buffer message in Windows platform and my coding language is C++. After serialization is done it returns "false". Please find the below code and let me know where I am going wrong.

Proto file

```
message mobile_list{    
required string name = 1;    
required DeviceType type = 2;    
required string imei = 3;    
required bytes wifiAddress = 4;    
optional bytes macAddress = 5;    
}
```

Protocol buffer Code

```
#include <unistd.h>    
#include "mobile.pb.h"    
#include <iostream>    
#include <google/protobuf/message.h>    
#include <google/protobuf/descriptor.h>    
#include <google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_stream_impl.h>    
#include <google/protobuf/io/coded_stream.h>    
#include <google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_stream_impl_lite.h>

using namespace google::protobuf::io;

using namespace std;
int main(int argv, char** argc){

mobile payload;
payload.set_name("Testing");
payload.set_type(mobile::Android);
payload.set_imei("123456");
payload.set_wifiAddress("96-00-OM-1E-4R-99");
payload.set_macAddress("96-00-OM-1E-4R-99");

int siz = payload.ByteSize();
char *pkt = new char [siz];
google::protobuf::io::ArrayOutputStream as(pkt,siz);
CodedOutputStream *coded_output = new CodedOutputStream(&as);
coded_output->WriteVarint32(payload.ByteSize());
payload.SerializeToCodedStream(coded_output);

return a.exec();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are allocating a buffer equal to the size of the message (`payload.ByteSize()`), but then you are trying to write into it a varint followed by the actual message. This adds up to more than the message size. The serialization is failing because it ran out of space.

You should do:

```
int siz = payload.ByteSize();
siz += CodedOutputStream::VarintSize32(siz);
// ... continue as before ...
```

Also, on an unrelated note, you are calling `ByteSize()` multiple times, which is wasteful because the whole message has to be scanned and counted each time. Instead, you should keep a copy of the original size to reuse.

Comment: You can call GetCachedSize() to avoid the recalculation as well.